# Two phase latch max delay constraint

Tags: flipflop, delay, timing

[image]

[image]

In this timing diagram, why am I not including tcpq, i.e. the latch clock to Q propagation delay?

Comment: Why are you not including it? Please tell us! Why are you not?

Comment: I dont know actually..it is given in neil weste harris..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses transparent latches instead of edge-triggered flip-flops, and notice that the data inputs (D1, D2, D3) are changing while the latch enable signals (\$\phi1\$ and \$\phi2\$) are high (asserted). Therefore, the important delay parameter is from when the input changes until the output is valid, \$t_{pdq}\$.

If the circuit used edge-triggered flip-flops then \$t_{cpq}\$ would be relevant. If the data inputs to the latches changed **only** while the latch enable was deasserted then the delay from the enable to Q would be relevant.

Comment: that means if i include the tcpq term..then it is not wrong..rt?

Comment: No, it means that you should **not** include \$t_{cpq}\$ for the example you give.

Comment: does this mean that for every latch based system i can ignore tcpq?

Comment: No, it means for a latch-based system **where the input data arrives after the enable has been asserted** you can ignore \$t_{cpq}\$.

Comment: Thank you very much.actually i have just started this chapter..can u provide some good informative links about these topics?